# Swift | How To Detect Sender And Receiver In Firebase

Tags: swift, database, firebase, mobile-application, social-media

I want to make a chatting app and I want to assign different colors and indent to sender and received messages. For example, sent message from the user is white ; received message is black. I could not figure it out. Thank you for in advance.

This is the app:

[Application Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oirOL.png)

For example in this image, second message is from the current user. I want to put this right.

I've tried this code in the file of the cell:

```
if let senderCode = Auth.auth().currentUser {
if document.get("postedBy") as! NSObject == senderCode {
self.tryLabel.text = "Sender"
}
else{
self.tryLabel.text = "Error"
}
}
```

But when i open the app tryLabel is equal to Error.

Comment: Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsattributedstring

Comment: Welcome to SO. We are not a code writing service and for us to help you, we need to see the code you've attempted and a description of the trouble you're having. Also, broad questions like this are really hard to answer as we don't know what part of the project you couldn't figure out - Firebase? TextFields? Coloring a View? Please take a moment and review [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)